# Convert numbers into words

Tags: javascript

```js
function convertAmountToWords(amount) {
  const words = [
    "Zero",
    "One",
    "Two",
    "Three",
    "Four",
    "Five",
    "Six",
    "Seven",
    "Eight",
    "Nine",
    "Ten",
    "Eleven",
    "Twelve",
    "Thirteen",
    "Fourteen",
    "Fifteen",
    "Sixteen",
    "Seventeen",
    "Eighteen",
    "Nineteen",
  ];

  const tensWords = [
    "",
    "",
    "Twenty",
    "Thirty",
    "Forty",
    "Fifty",
    "Sixty",
    "Seventy",
    "Eighty",
    "Ninety",
  ];

  const centsWords = [
    "",
    "One Cent",
    "Two Cents",
    "Three Cents",
    "Four Cents",
    "Five Cents",
    "Six Cents",
    "Seven Cents",
    "Eight Cents",
    "Nine Cents",
  ];

  const [dollars, cents] = amount.slice(1).split(".");
  const dollarWords =
    dollars === "0" ?
    "Zero" :
    dollars < 20 ?
    words[Number(dollars)] :
    tensWords[Math.floor(dollars / 10)] +
    (dollars % 10 === 0 ? "" : ` ${words[dollars % 10]}`);
  const centWords = cents ? centsWords[Number(cents)] : "";

  return `${dollarWords} Dollar and ${centWords}`;
}

const amountInWords = convertAmountToWords("$10.20");
console.log(amountInWords); // Output: "Ten Dollar and Twenty Cents"
```

In this code example that (.20) is undefined, I want to above example is ($10.20),
I want "Ten Dollar and Twenty Cents".
How to recode above example.
Help me please.

Comment: Why do you need separate number words for dollars and cents?

Comment: The algorithm for converting a number to words is the same whether it's dollars or cents.

Comment: Your `centWords` array only goes up to Nine.

Comment: Your getting the word *Twenty Cents*, but your ```centsWords``` until "Nine Cents" only. Maybe that's lacking there so you're getting **undefined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `centsWords` array only goes up to nine. So instead of creating a new array, it's easier and better to use the same array and the same method you used to generate the `dollarWords`.

```
function convertAmountToWords(amount) {
  const words = [
    "Zero",
    "One",
    "Two",
    "Three",
    "Four",
    "Five",
    "Six",
    "Seven",
    "Eight",
    "Nine",
    "Ten",
    "Eleven",
    "Twelve",
    "Thirteen",
    "Fourteen",
    "Fifteen",
    "Sixteen",
    "Seventeen",
    "Eighteen",
    "Nineteen",
  ];

  const tensWords = [
    "",
    "",
    "Twenty",
    "Thirty",
    "Forty",
    "Fifty",
    "Sixty",
    "Seventy",
    "Eighty",
    "Ninety",
  ];

  const [dollars, cents] = amount.slice(1).split(".");
  const dollarWords = (
    dollars === "0" ?
      "Zero"
    :
      dollars < 20 ?
        words[dollars]
      :
        tensWords[Math.floor(dollars / 10)] + (dollars % 10 === 0 ? "" : ` ${words[dollars % 10]}`)
  );
  const centWords = (
    cents === "0" ?
      "Zero"
    :
      cents < 20 ?
        words[cents]
      :
        tensWords[Math.floor(cents / 10)] + (cents % 10 === 0 ? "" : ` ${words[cents % 10]}`)
  );

  return `${dollarWords} Dollar and ${centWords} Cent`;
}
```

Comment: Your code snippet is perfect. Thank you.